# how to show the limit of the maximal solution of an ODE system exists

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I have this exercise extracted from an exercise sheet the teacher gave us about qualitative theory of ODE (in which we study the existence and uniqueness of solutions, and stability using the function of Lyapunov)

I don't know how to solve it: For 1. it's ok but from 2. and 3. I don't have any idea.

Let $k> 0$. Note $(x(t),y(t)),t\in I$ the maximal solution of

$\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             \frac{dx}{dt}\, =\, y &   ,x(0)=x_0 \\
             \\ \frac{dy}{dt}\, =\, x(1-x^2)-ky &  ,y(0)=y_0
             \end{array}
   \right.$

Let $A(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(x^2-1)^2+y^2$ and for $k>0$ the function $A$ is a function of Lyapunov

1. Show that the solution exists for all positive times
2. Show that $\lim_{t\to+\infty}(x(t),y(t))$ exists.
3. What happens for $k <0$ and $k = 0$

For 1. I used the following result

> **Theorem:** If $\dot{x}=f(x)$ has a Lyapunov function and if for all $R>0$, the set $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: V(x)\leq R\}$ is bounded then the maximal solution of Cauchy's problem is global in positive time.

I don't know how to solve  2. and 3.

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For $k>0$, can the solution stabilize on any positive level of $A$?

$k=0$ should be easy, as $A$ is also a first integral.

For $k<0$, can you bound the growth of $A$ in terms of $A$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I think that for $k>0$ I should study if $\frac{dA}{dt}>0$ or $\frac{dA}{dt}<0$. But still I'm sorry, but I don't understand how can the solution stabilize on any positive level of $A$ and how you used the first integral A. Could you explain that? I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: For $k>0$ I think that I can't bound the growth of $A$ in terms of $A$

Comment: I had mixed up the sign of $k$. The system describes the mechanical motion in a double-well potential under a friction force with coefficient $k$, for $k>0$ the system will continuously lose energy $E=\frac12A$ until it is at a minimum, for $k>0$ energy is added to the system making it oscillate with ever greater amplitude.

Comment: How do you study $\lim_{t\to+\infty}(x(t),y(t))$? I'm still a little confused on this part.

Comment: $A$ is non-increasing and bounded below. As there are no stationary points with positive $A$, the limit has to be zero. Now $A=0$ has a finite set of real solutions.